video issue building vue project with vite
I built my portfolio website with vite & vue3 and hosted it on Netlify, now I have an issue with my website I have a project page with a video of the project, and the videos are stored in '/assets/works/example.mp4' but when I build it using 'npm run build' the videos not showing up in the 'dist' folder. I will be glad to hear a solution or another approach.
playing with vite config and make the videos appear in the dist folder.

Try to put it in the public directory: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/public oh wait, are you using Nuxt or just Vue?

You need to add your .mp4 in your public directory, then it will copy in your dist directory. the public folder is served on / so you can now access your file with /path/to/your/.mp4/under/public/directory.
Public directory

Would have been easier expressed as /public/path_to_mp4.

No the public isn't part of the path

Then /path_to_mp4.

I think if had put /path_to_mp4 he would have been tempted to start the path with /public
